# Creating a from an azure logic app not working

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to create a blob from a storage account but can't find the storage account from the create form. Here is what I did.

I made the storage account
[image: First I make a storage account:]

I then made a new blob service container in this storage account called log:
[image: I then made a new blob service container called log:]

I have a consumption logic app that looks like this:
[image: I have a consumption logic app that looks like this:]

It was made with these configurations:
[image: It was made with these configurations:]

In the logic app designer, I add a step of type action. I select create blob V2.

But when I try to find my storage account it isn't in the list.
[image: But when I try to find my storage account it isn't in the list.]

Do you know what happened or at least tell me how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro the same scenario in my lab, I was able to create Storage account and logic app with same configuration which you referred and connect them.

Refer to the below mentioned steps!

**Step 1:** Create a Storage Account .

[image]

**Step 2:** Create a Logic App (Consumption).

[image]

**Step 3 :** Create a container inside the storage account .

[image]

**Step 4:** Go to Logic App designer and add the step `“Create a Blob”`

[image]

> **Note :** Please make sure to have a correct connection made to the storage account in the above step. If not sure then click on change connection in the above step and add a new connection .- Refer the below Steps !

**Steps to set a Connection to the storage account using access key:**

[image]

**Step 1 :** Get the details for the above by going to the Storage account Page in the portal and clicking on the Access keys.

[image]

**Step 2:** Click on show keys to view and copy the details required for adding the connection in  logic app . Use either Key1 or Key2 details . In connection name (Logic app) please copy the connection string (in storage account access key1 or 2 ) and in Azure storage account access key (Logic app) please copy the key (in storage account key 1 or 2 ). Please make sure you are using the key and connection string both either for key1 or key 2 .

[image]

**Step 3:** Click on create and connection to the storage account will be made and then  the Storage account can be successfully seen in logic app .

[image]

**Reference:**

[How to connect the azure blob storage to logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage?tabs=single-tenant)

> **Note :** Logic apps can't directly access storage accounts that are behind firewalls if they're both in the same region. As a workaround, you can have your logic apps and storage account in different regions. For more information about enabling access from Azure Logic Apps to storage accounts behind firewalls, see the [Access storage accounts behind firewalls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage?tabs=single-tenant#access-storage-accounts-behind-firewalls)